# passportjs facebook authentication strategy

Tags: facebook, authentication, passport.js

let's say a user logs in via facebook. At some point later he wants to add his facebook friends.

Both actions require FB authentication, but in passport.js you only have one facebookstrategy, right?

Ideally I would subclass the existing FB strategy into

- FBLoginStrategy
- FBGetFriendsStrategy

, each with a dedicated callbackURL

what is the recommended strategy to do this?

[I don't want to rely on the previously obtained accessToken, since it might be expired. refreshing these would require an extra caching/storing strategy]

Comment: This will help: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook/issues/2